# Creating UIViews Programmatically doesn't work in Xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, snapkit

I want to create an UIView as a container view or even more programmatically with the snapkit in Xcode 11.1, but it seems there is something wrong and I think Apple has changed UIView in Xcode 11.x (iOS 13.x) because I did it very easily in the previous versions of Xcode.

In SceneDelegate.swift (Apple has moved the window variable from AppDelegate.swift to SceneDelegate.swift)

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        setUpView()
    }
    
    func setUpView() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.snp.centerX)
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.snp.centerY)
        }
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To displaying a view using autolayout, you need to provide all `W H X Y` satisfy the layout engine. But you missed `width` and `height` constraints.

Try this:

```
func setUpView() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.height.equalTo(100)
        make.center.equalTo(self.view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the height and width of your container view.

```
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```